# Need vertification that I am coding the requirements correctly in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am very basic at JavaScript and I am not the best at it. I wanted to make sure I am coding this all correctly, if someone can verify or correct me. It will be much appreciated. Thank you. Here are the requirements:

[image: Requirements]

Here is my code:

```
//Global variables.
window.onload = initPage;
var memoryArray[22] = ['A','A','B','B','C','C','D','D','E','E','F','F','H','H','I','I','J','J','K','K','L','L'];
var memoryValues = [];
var memoryTiles = [];
var tilesFlipped = 0;
var startingTime = 60;
var memoryBoard = document.getElementById("memoryBoard");
var time = document.getElementById("time");
var startButton = document.getElementById("newGame");
var message = document.getElementById("message"); 
//Method that ties startbutton to newgame method.
startButton.onclick;
```

Comment: Requirements mix camel-case and lowercase, `memoryvalues` is all lowercase. Just as a start. Note that if this was a voluntary project, i'd have closed the tutorial upon reading this, and went elsewhere. It also has typos, e.g. "variablecalled" in the last point.

Comment: lol, I agree with you..

Comment: Just to mention this again, unlike the requirements, you wrote it as `memoryValues`, with capital V. You also still lack the last two points. `startButton.onclick;` doesnt make any sense on itself, and you still need to create the variable `timer`.

Comment: @ASDFGerte, yea I fixed that camel-casing issue. For the startbutton is for requirements letter I. Would it be startButton.onclick = newGame; ?

Answer (score 0):

your startButton.onlick should be 
`startButton.onclick = newGameMethod`
As startButton.onclick does not point to anything